# Following Redirects when calling API - RestSharp versus Postman

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, postman, restsharp

How do I align Postman and Restsharp to follow redirects in the same way?

I had a API call using OAuth v2 where my calls where fine in Postman but the same call using RestSharp resulted in an authorisation error. I got the token no problem on both but using this token against the API endpoint working in Postman but failed with an authorisatoin error in RestSharp.

I finally worked out the problem was that the endpoint actually returned a 307 response as the URL I had been given was missing a trailing slash.

```
client.FollowRedirects = false;
```

was the key to working this out in the RestSharp call however it was by no means obvious and took me a long time to debug and work out.

I can not find a way to align the redirect actions of RestSharp and Postman in these type of circumstances, is there a way to do this to avoid this type of problem?

Comment: Are you saying RestSharp isn't redirecting automatically?

Comment: I am saying that the way it redirects is dfferent. RestSharp follows the redirect OK (in this case it was a 307) by default but ends with an authentication error. Postman also redirects by default but works fine. Like a lot of C# devs I use Newtonsoft.json with RestSharp to implement APIs but try them first in Postman. Would be nice if my setup had the same funtionality on both to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1229

For more info on redirection and authentication headers in RestSharp. So setting FollowRedirects to false is probably the only way as Postman is doing the right thing and RestSharp is not it would seem.